# Getting error while connecting to MySQL in Golang

Tags: mysql, go

My code looks like this

```
connStr := fmt.Sprintf("%s:%s@%s(%s:%d)/%s", USERNAME, PASSWORD, NETWORK, SERVER, PORT, DATABASE)

conn, err := sql.Open("mymysql", connStr)
checkErr(err)
dbl.Conn = conn
```

When I run it, thrown error code:

```
2020/09/06 15:16:01 [Recovery] 2020/09/06 - 15:16:01 panic recovered:
POST /signin HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 0
Password: ccc
Postman-Token: ff5f3d30-925e-40bc-9016-305b488e9476
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.26.2
Username: ggg
```

```
Wrong database part of URI
/Users/liuda/IdeaProjects/go_workspace/dehm/main/dbLinker.go:57 (0x1656393)
        checkErr: panic(err)
/Users/liuda/IdeaProjects/go_workspace/dehm/main/dbLinker.go:43 (0x165635f)
        DbLinker.Signin: checkErr(err)
/Users/liuda/IdeaProjects/go_workspace/dehm/main/signin.go:26 (0x16569a6)
        Signin: linker.Signin(sd)
/Users/liuda/IdeaProjects/go_test/pkg/mod/github.com/gin-gonic/gin@v1.6.3/context.go:161 (0x154ab1a)
        (*Context).Next: c.handlers[c.index](c)
/Users/liuda/IdeaProjects/go_test/pkg/mod/github.com/gin-gonic/gin@v1.6.3/recovery.go:83 (0x155eb04)
        RecoveryWithWriter.func1: c.Next()
/Users/liuda/IdeaProjects/go_test/pkg/mod/github.com/gin-gonic/gin@v1.6.3/context.go:161 (0x154ab1a)
        (*Context).Next: c.handlers[c.index](c)
/Users/liuda/IdeaProjects/go_test/pkg/mod/github.com/gin-gonic/gin@v1.6.3/logger.go:241 (0x155dc04)
        LoggerWithConfig.func1: c.Next()
/Users/liuda/IdeaProjects/go_test/pkg/mod/github.com/gin-gonic/gin@v1.6.3/context.go:161 (0x154ab1a)
        (*Context).Next: c.handlers[c.index](c)
/Users/liuda/IdeaProjects/go_test/pkg/mod/github.com/gin-gonic/gin@v1.6.3/gin.go:409 (0x1554e59)
        (*Engine).handleHTTPRequest: c.Next()
/Users/liuda/IdeaProjects/go_test/pkg/mod/github.com/gin-gonic/gin@v1.6.3/gin.go:367 (0x155454c)
        (*Engine).ServeHTTP: engine.handleHTTPRequest(c)
/usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2843 (0x1328562)
        serverHandler.ServeHTTP: handler.ServeHTTP(rw, req)
/usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:1925 (0x1323c6c)
        (*conn).serve: serverHandler{c.server}.ServeHTTP(w, w.req)
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1374 (0x106bd80)
        goexit: BYTE    $0x90   // NOP
```

Can anyone help me, how to fix this issue?

Comment: The error tells you the database part of the URI is wrong, it's probably empty. Log the built URI and check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I had to guess, your `PORT` variable is a `string` not a `int` and silently producing an invalid `DSN` e.g.

```
fmt.Printf("%s:%s@%s(%s:%d)/%s", `user`, `secr3t`, `tcp`, `mydbsrv`, `3306`, `mydb`)
// `user:secr3t@tcp(mydbsrv:%!d(string=3306))/mydb` - invalid DSN
```

Log the DSN prior to `sql.Open` to verify - and if that is indeed the issue: I'd encourage you to use mysql's [Config.FormatDSN](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql?tab=doc#Config.FormatDSN) instead, to ensure safely encoded DSN addresses:

```
c := mysql.Config{
    User:                    "user",
    Passwd:                  "secr3t",
    Net:                     "tcp",
    Addr:                    "mydbsrv:3306",
    DBName:                  "mydb",
    Params:                  map[string]string{"charset": "utf8"}, // optional
    ParseTime:               true,                                 // optional
}
fmt.Println(c.FormatDSN())
```

https://play.golang.org/p/kOvruaWiwsp